# Why do these values not equal each other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, slice

```
var student = new Object();
student.classes = ["Digital Photography","Chemistry I","Art of Film","Business in Microcomputer Applications","Study Hall","Algebra 2","Careers","Business Math"]

function newStudent(){
    var studentName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var one = document.getElementById("1").value;
    var two = document.getElementById("2").value;
    var three = document.getElementById("3").value;
    var four = document.getElementById("4").value;
    var five = document.getElementById("5").value;
    var six = document.getElementById("6").value;
    var seven = document.getElementById("7").value;
    var eight = document.getElementById("8").value;
    var newStudent = new Object();
    newStudent.name = studentName;
    newStudent.classes = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight];
    if(student.classes.slice(0,1) == newStudent.classes.slice(0,1)){
        alert('You share first hour with Student');
    } else {
        alert("You have " + newStudent.classes.slice(0,1) + " instead of " + student.classes.slice(0,1));
    }
}
```

Why, if I input Digital Photography as newStudent's first class does not show the alert telling the user they share that class?

ignore the sloppy code I was tired and now I am tired and confused.

Comment: Because you're comparing two different arrays. `.slice` gives you a new array. Try looping.

Comment: @elclanrs if the values of the .slice is the same, should it not come back as true if I test to see if they are equal?

Comment: Nope, comparing arrays directly compares by object identity. If you want to compare the contents of the array, you have to loop and compare each one.

Comment: Could someone post an example of looping and comparing arrays, then I will implement it into mine so I still learn something?

Comment: you redeclare `var student`, first global, second local, and local was string, not array of string

Comment: I am more of a visual learner. If you were to post an answer showing this, I would learn much quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `student.classes.slice(0,1)` you get array with one element, so to get its element use indexer

```
...
if(student.classes.slice(0,1)[0] == newStudent.classes.slice(0,1)[0]){
...
```

Comment: In the code I am running I don't have the global student variable, I just changed the wording out for personal reasons.

Comment: @TheWalkingPacifist i was guided by your sample :-)

Comment: And you did a mighty fine job thank you :)
I will change my sample so that doesn't occur